# Should I use Strategy Pattern for this task?

Tags: design-patterns, excel, vba

I'm setting up a data validator that will iterate through the rows of a spreadsheet, and for each column, perform a validation check.  I was thinking that this might be an appropriate task for the Strategy Pattern as follows:

interface IValidator:

```
public function isValid(rng as range) as boolean
end function
```

implementation validator_Number:

```
'checks whether or not value is a number    
implements IValidator
public function IValidator_isValid(rng as range) as boolean
    IValidator_isValid=isnumeric(rng.value)
end function
```

implementation validator_Capitalized:

```
'checks whether all letters are capitalized in value
implements IValidator
public function IValidator_isValid(rng as range) as boolean
   IValidator_isValid=isnumeric(rng.value) and (ucase(rng.value)=rng.value) 
end function
```

validation checker:

```
'iterates through worksheet cells, validating them and 
public sub validationChecker()

dim headerRow as long
dim validator as IValidator

headerRow=1

for row=2 to maxRow
    for column=1 to maxColumn
        'check the column header name and instantiate
        'validator using the appropriate implementation
        select case sheet.cells(headerRow,column).value
            case "NAME"
                set validator=new validator_Capitalized
            case "AGE"
                set validator=new validator_Number
            'etc.
         end select
         if validator.isValid(sheet.cells(row,column)) then
             doSomething()
         endif
     next
next
```

I previously asked [another question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/184727/class-structure-pattern-for-validating-several-different-excel-templates) about using Strategy to validate Excel data, and the response was that I didn't need to do that because there were only a few types of tests and so the rules could be held in a data store.  But here there are going to be many different kinds of validation tests, some of which have several lines of code.  Is the Strategy implementation that I outlined above the most appropriate pattern to use here?

Comment: The first design pattern I think of when I read your problem is [visitor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`isValid()` could be a method implemented in a Strategy pattern. IMO, the benefit of the pattern is future modifiability. That is, there will be a future need for new implementations of `isValid()` and you don't want to change your code that iterates and validates. In the definition of Strategy, that's the `Context` class.

[image: Strategy pattern]

Your `select` block, which I believe would be in the `Context` class, isn't flexible the way you proposed it, mainly because it "knows" the concrete implementations:

```
    select case sheet.cells(headerRow,column).value
        case "NAME"
            set validator=new validator_Capitalized
        case "AGE"
            set validator=new validator_Number
        'etc.
     end select
```

To make Strategy work the way you want, you probably need a Simple Factory that encapsulates the `new XXX`. So, instead of a select/case, you just do:

```
    set validator = Factory.create(sheet.cells(headerRow,column).value)
```

which effectively calls a `create` method with the argument "NAME", "AGE", etc. which will return the appropriate validator. The `create()` encapsulates the select/case logic.

The benefit of this is that you can add new validators without having to change the code in `Context`. Of course, you *do* have to update the `Factory.create()` method (essentially the new case for a new validator) and write a new `IValidator` implementation.

Here's an updated diagram:

[image: Strategy with simple factory]

The factory class as well as the separate implementation classes are a lot of extra code which IMO won't "pay off" if you only have two validators and a single `Context`. If you plan on adding lots of validators and really want the flexibility of keeping the details hidden from `Context` (which may appear in several places), then go for it!

If you aren't "feeling pain" from repetition in maintaining code, then probably you don't need a pattern.